# Erro: Undefined variable 'x' in 'local'

Tags: php, mysql

Estou aprendendo **PHP**, na página aparece isso:

> "Notice: Undefined variable: tarefas in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 42."

```
Código PHP:
<?php

$bdServidor = '127.0.0.1';
$bdUsuario = 'felipe';
$bdSenha = 'testeteste123' ;
$bdbanco = 'tarefas' ;

$conexao = mysqli_connect($bdServidor,$bdUsuario,$bdSenha,$bdbanco);

if (mysqli_connect_errno($conexao)) 
{
echo "Problemas para conectar no banco. Verifique os dados!";
}
else
{
  echo "tudo ocorreu bem";
}
function busca_tarefas($conexao)
{
    $sqlBusca = 'SELECT * FROM tarefas';
    $resultado = mysql_query($conexao,$sqlBusca);
    $tarefas= array();
    while($tarefa =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) 
    {
        $tarefas[] = $tarefa;
    }
    return $tarefas;
}
?>

Código HTML:
<?php
session_start();
include "tarefas.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tarefas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
<center><form method="GET">
    <fieldset id="felipe">
        <legend>Nova tarefa</legend>
        <label>Nome
            <input class="theme" type="text" name="nome">
        </label><br>
        <label>descrição
            <textarea class="themee" name="descricao"></textarea>
        </label><br>
        <label>Prazo
            <input class="theme" type="text" name="prioridade">
        </label><br>
        <fieldset id="felipee">
            <legend>Prioridade</legend>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="alta">Alta
            <input type="radio" name="media">Média
            <input type="radio" name="baixa">Baixa
        </label><br>
        </fieldset><br>
        <input type="submit" name="enviar">
    </fieldset>
</form></center>
     <table border='1px'>
        <tr>
            <td>Nome</td>
            <td>descricao</td>
            <td>prioridade</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php print_r($tarefas)
            ?></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Como posso corrigir este erro?

Comment: O erro está na linha 42 conforme você mesmo postou: "... Undefined variable: tarefas in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 42."...". Variável não definida em index.php na linha 42

Comment: Mas como posso arrumar?

Comment: Por favor, faça um titulo intuitivo para a pergunta, escrever Ajuda por favor é totalmente redundante, todos que estão perguntando no site já estão procurando por ajuda, então isso é óbvio, escrever um titulo util definindo o problema ajuda a aumentar o interesse das pessoas.

Comment: @FelipheStival Arrogancia é algo bem diferente de dizer o óbvio, foi o que eu disse e sem nenhuma intenção de te ofender, é erro de digitação ou falta de aprender o básico. Respondi e expliquei como usa e a questão do escopo, mandar alguém "enfiar algo no **" pra revidar algo soe como critica é agir de maneira totalmente desproporcional e desnecessária o que mostra que você ainda precisa aprender a tirar proveito das coisas, mesmo da pior situação, e amadurecer mais para evitar se ofender gratuitamente. Então não use de xingamentos e procure aceitar e entender as orientações sobre códigos.

Answer (score 5):

Creio que deveria ser no lugar disto:

```
 <td><?php print_r($tarefas)
        ?></td>
```

Isto:

```
 <td><?php
   $tarefas = busca_tarefas($conexao);
   print_r($tarefas);
   ?></td>
```

Porque até aonde entendo funções não se executam sozinhas e a variavel $tarefas esta dentro do escopo e no `return`, ou seja tem que passar para uma variavel fora do escopo da função, `$tarefas =`.

Me parece que foi ou algum erro de digitação de sua parte ou falta de compreender o básico do que é uma função.